# Adjust footnote size and justification in R Markdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown, knitr, footnotes

I am writing my thesis in R Markdown and want to alter the formatting of the footnotes in the PDF document. How can I:

1. Adjust the font size to 10pt?
2. Change the justification of the text?

Answer (score 2):

You can include LaTeX commands to overwrite the size of text within the template. For footnote, you can lter the size of the font using any of the [LaTeX commands](https://texblog.org/2012/08/29/changing-the-font-size-in-latex/), replacing the `\normalsize` if you want larger text.

The text has been fully justified with `\justify` command, which comes from the LaTeX package `ragged2e`

```
---
output:
  pdf_document
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{ragged2e}
  - \renewcommand{\footnotesize}{\normalsize \justify}
---

This is some text^[This is a footnote which is fully justified. Some filler text, more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text more filler text]
```

[image]

> As a warning, if you are planning on writing your thesis in R Markdown, I would make sure you are familiar with LaTeX! It will be required to achieve some of the customised formatting required.